# WPF TextBox border not changing properly with validation

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I'm trying to get the border of my TextBox to turn red when an error is found. Right now it just makes a red square in the top left corner of the TextBox. The validation definitely works as intended, I'm just having a hard time getting the border to do what I need it to.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Login, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                     IsEnabled="{Binding LoginEnabled}"
                     Width="141" Margin="10">
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: you forgot `<AdornedElementPlaceholder/>` inside border

Comment: @ASh That is perfect, thank you!